# alternating fill color in a line of squares

Tags: colors, turtle-graphics, fill, python-turtle

I'm trying to make a line of squares that alternate between two colors, but it only runs the first color. We've been going over building our own functions and using the modulo operator, so that's how I'm trying to alternate the colors. I'm not sure what's going wrong.

Here's the code I've been trying. I guess I missed something but I don't know what I'm not understanding about why the color won't change. I have tried moving the if/else but that didn't change anything and I'm pretty sure it should be inside the first for loop.

```
def square_line(num_squares, color1, color2):
  for square in range(num_squares):
    if num_squares % 2 == 1:
      t.fillcolor(color1)
    else:
      t.fillcolor(color2)
    t.begin_fill()
    for sides in range(4):
      t.forward(25)
      t.right(90)
    t.end_fill()
    t.penup()
    t.forward(25)
    t.pendown()

square_line(6, 'blue', 'green')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this bit of your code:

```py
if num_squares % 2 == 1:
```

you are telling your program to fill with `color1` if num_squares is odd, otherwise fill with `color2`, and as num_squares doesn't change, this only fills one color.
I'd recommend doing something like:

```py
for square in range(num_squares):
    if square % 2 == 1: # not: num_squares % 2 == 1
        t.fillcolor(color1)
    else:
        t.fillcolor(color2)
    ...
```

As the value of `square` alternates between odd and even each iteration, this will change the fill color each iteration.